# MySQL: Select Distinct across multiple tables and order by datetime

Tags: mysql, distinct

This is a tricky one to explain, let's see if I can.

I'm looking for a way in mysql to select the latest 5 entries (ordered by datetime desc) by  ***distinct*** pids across three tables.

Below is an example.

**TABLE1**
*NOTE that the column id in TABLE 1 needs to be substitued with pid to match the other tables (select id as pid).

```
  id*   datetime
|-----|------------|
|  1  |  1/1/2000  |
|  2  |  2/1/2000  |
|  3  |  3/1/2000  | ← two
|  4  |  1/3/2000  | ← five
|  5  |  1/3/2000  |
```

**TABLE2**

```
  id    pid    datetime
|-----|-----|------------|
|  1  |  1  |  1/2/2000  |
|  2  |  1  |  1/2/2000  |
|  3  |  2  |  2/2/2000  | ← three
|  4  |  3  |  1/2/2000  |
|  5  |  5  |  1/4/2000  | ← four
```

**TABLE3**

```
  id    pid    datetime
|-----|-----|------------|
|  1  |  1  |  6/1/2000  | ← one
|  2  |  1  |  1/1/2000  |
|  3  |  1  |  1/1/2000  |
|  4  |  2  |  1/1/2000  |
|  5  |  3  |  1/1/2000  |
```

**Result would be**

```
  pid    datetime
|-----|------------|
|  1  |  6/1/2000  | ← one
|  3  |  3/1/2000  | ← two
|  2  |  2/2/2000  | ← three
|  5  |  1/4/2000  | ← four
|  4  |  1/3/2000  | ← five
```

I'm pretty new to mysql.  I've searched around and this is the best I've come up with so far, but it's totally wrong. Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pid, datetime 
   from (SELECT id AS pid, datetime FROM table1
         UNION
         SELECT pid, datetime FROM table2
         UNION
         SELECT pid, datetime from table3) t
   ORDER BY datetime DESC
   LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Unless you swap the `id` and `pid` column names in `table2`, row `four` will not be in the result set.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm not sure what you mean?  Does your answer below not include row four in the result set?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You select the column `pid` which has the value `3` not `5`. For pid 5, the resulting row will be `5 | 1/3/2000`.

Comment: Oh, right - you are correct.  That was just a typo on my example, I will fix it above so others will understand the intent of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick the maximum date of each pid

```
SELECT pid, max(`datetime`) as `datetime`
from (SELECT id AS pid, `datetime` FROM table1
      UNION
      SELECT pid, `datetime` FROM table2
      UNION
      SELECT pid, `datetime` from table3) t
group by pid
ORDER BY max(`datetime`) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This appears to be working great with my real db.  thanks tons!